# Masking phone numbers in big data

Tags: encryption, aes, bigdata, sha

We have large dataset (many columns) which has almost 50 million unique phone numbers. We are intending to upload the data into Amazon S3 on a routine basis (daily or weekly). But first, it is vital that we scramble or mask the phone numbers, the other fields can be left as is.

Using fruits as analogus to the phone numbers, I explain my below problems.

**Options considered.** 

1) Aggregate all the data by phone numbers and assign each number a unique value. 

*The problem is that this is a not a consistent approach.*

1st Time             2nd time 
apple - v1           apple - v1
banana -v2         cherry -v2
cherry -v3 
This can only be an one-off solution at best.

2) Use SHA-1 to generate a hash and store it in some local table. Then we can use this local table to reference the original values from the keys later.
*The problem is that SHA-1 **might** have duplicate hashes even with salt added.Not sure whether possible to maintain unique hash table*
apple -  asjdfaslkdfj 
banana - blajsdfkljas 
cherry - blajsdfkljas (is this possible)

3) Use AES to encrypt the data. 
*Is it possible to encrypt just a column, cos AES seems to be able to encrypt the whole file.
Another issue, is that speed might become very slow to encrypt so much data.* I am just Thinking Out Aloud here.

Can anyone recommend a suitable solution for this problem ?

Comment: Phone Numbers shouldn't generate collisions on SHA as their address space is very limited, the collisions occur when the original data has a broad range of characters and can be "manipulated", here you have pseudo-unique phone numbers, I think you should be ok

Comment: Agree with nrathaus - there are `2^160` SHA1 digests possible, and only around `10^15` phone numbers possible. That's `10^33` times as many digests as phone numbers. If this was a severe concern for you, you could probably precompute the SHA1 digests for all possible phone numbers once (probably would just take a few weeks tops if you had enough good machines since this is extremely parallelizable) to verify that there are no collisions.

Comment: Do you know that nobody in history has *ever* generated a SHA-1 collision, let alone on such a small input? And e.g. IAIK has really been trying, even using grid computing. If you manage to create one, please don't forget to inform the crypto community, you'll probably be invited to nice meetings and such :)

Comment: Thanks for SHA-1 clarification.How about on AES qn ?

Comment: To make sure collision doesnt ever occur, I thought of this stratagy.<br/> Hash = SHA1(salt()+phone_num) ... I have used salt() function which will generate a random string to make it more scrambled.